# Why is my CNN model predicting wrong when the accuracy is high?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

so I built a CNN image classification model with an accuracy of ~84%, but when I try to predict an image, it always gets it wrong.

This is the model that I used:

````
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape = array_image.shape))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(numberOfClass)) #output
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))
    model.compile(loss = "categorical_cross```entropy",
             optimizer = "rmsprop",
             metrics = ["accuracy"])
    return model
````

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.3,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    zoom_range = 0.3)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
```

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = array_image.shape[:2],
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "categorical")
```

```
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size = array_image.shape[:2],
    batch_size = batch_size,
    color_mode = "rgb",
    class_mode = "categorical")
```

```
for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    print("data_batch shape --> ",data_batch.shape)
    print("labels_batch shape --> ",labels_batch.shape)
    break
```

```
es_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=4, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_dir, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)

hist = model.fit(
    x = train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = 1600 // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_data = test_generator,
    callbacks = [es_callback, cp_callback],
    validation_steps = 800 // batch_size)
```

*Epoch 29: saving model to Attempt No. 5/checkpoint\weights-improvement-29-0.84.hdf5
50/50 [==============================] - 50s 1s/step - loss: 0.5336 - accuracy: 0.8425 - val_loss: 0.2806 - val_accuracy: 0.9000*

Yes I know that the train data and the test data are the same, but I don't think that should be impacting it that much because the separate data that I am predicting is also from that same dataset.

```
test_img = [
    load_img(test_dir + "0/1-30226-A-0.wav.png"),
    load_img(test_dir + "0/1-30344-A-0.wav.png"),
    load_img(test_dir + "0/1-32318-A-0.wav.png"),
    load_img(test_dir + "0/1-59513-A-0.wav.png"),
    load_img(test_dir + "0/1-85362-A-0.wav.png"),
    load_img(test_dir + "0/1-97392-A-0.wav.png")
]

test_arr = [
    img_to_array(test_img[0]),
    img_to_array(test_img[1]),
    img_to_array(test_img[2]),
    img_to_array(test_img[3]),
    img_to_array(test_img[4]),
    img_to_array(test_img[5])
]
test_ = np.array(test_arr)

print(test_.shape)

pred_0, pred_1, pred_2, pred_3, pred_4, pred_5 = model.predict(test_)

print(classes[pred_0.tolist().index(max(pred_0.tolist()))])
print(classes[pred_1.tolist().index(max(pred_1.tolist()))])
print(classes[pred_2.tolist().index(max(pred_2.tolist()))])
print(classes[pred_3.tolist().index(max(pred_3.tolist()))])
print(classes[pred_4.tolist().index(max(pred_4.tolist()))])
print(classes[pred_5.tolist().index(max(pred_5.tolist()))])
```

*(6, 128, 216, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 414ms/step
toilet_flush
clapping
clock_tick
rain
crackling_fire
clapping*

^supposed to be all dogs

Comment: What is your data? What are the labels? What is the class balance in training/serving? What do you mean by "it always gets it wrong"?

Comment: Common mistake, you are not applying the rescale normalization after loading new images, this is applied in your generator so the model expects normalized inputs.